# Removing text from a box regardless of location

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

```
Private Sub CBFRANK_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CBFRANK.CheckedChanged
    If CBFRANK.Checked = True Then
        existsub = subjectBox.Text
        rollingsub = existsub + "FR, "
        existfull = FullName.Text
        rollingfull = existfull + "Franklin Hospital, "
        subjectBox.Text = rollingsub
        FullName.Text = rollingfull
    Else
        Replace(FullName.Text, "Franklin Hospital, ", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Thats what I have, and what it does is basically when you check a box it adds "ZHH, " to one text box and "Zucker Hillside Hospital, " to another.

What I want to be able to do is search those text boxes when the property is unchecked and I want it to just remove those additions regardless of where they are

So imagine I have this in the respective boxes:

XXX, ZHH, XXX

And in the other box

XXX Hospital, Zucker Hillside Hospital, XXX Hospital

I want to be able to remove both ZHH and Zucker Hillside Hospital from their respective boxes regardless of where they are in the string

The event handler would be the unchecked function the other "if"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) searching for the text to remove and setting an empty string in its place

```
Private Sub CBZUCK_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CBZUCK.CheckedChanged
    If CBZUCK.Checked = True Then
        subjectBox.Text = subjectBox.Text & "ZHH, "
        FullName.Text = FullName.Text & "Zucker Hillside Hospital, "
    Else
        subjectBox.Text = subjectBox.Text.Replace("ZHH, ", "")
        FullName.Text = FullName.Text.Replace("Zucker Hillside Hospital, ", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function Replace(), like this

```
replace(myString,"ZHH","")
```

so it's replace every instance of ZHH bu nothing.

Beware that it can erase ZHHYTVF and leave YTVF.  It might not want that.

Answer (score 0):

`If CBZUCK.Checked = True Then
        subjectBox.Text = subjectBox.Text & "ZHH, "
        FullName.Text = FullName.Text & "Zucker Hillside Hospital, "
    Else
        subjectBox.Text = subjectBox.Text.Replace("ZHH, ", "")
        FullName.Text = FullName.Text.Replace("Zucker Hillside Hospital, ", "")
    End If
End Sub`

Thank you!